# Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear trasformation. Find $T(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, transformation

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear trasformation with

$T
  \left(\begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\
   -2 \\
   -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}  $  and $T
  \left(\begin{bmatrix}
     -2 \\
   1 \\
   3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    -2 \\
    4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}  $ find $T
  \left(\begin{bmatrix}
     -1 \\
   -4 \\
   3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\right) = $

Can someone help me out with this its not making sense to me

Comment: Well apparently the image is actually in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but as a first try I would see if I could make the vector youre looking to transform from a linear combination of the two you know about; then calculating its image is easy by exploiting linearity of $T$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we could find scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-4\\3\end{bmatrix}=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}
$$
then the linearity of $T$ would imply that
\begin{align*}
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-4\\3\end{bmatrix}\right)
&=\alpha T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right)+\beta T\left(\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}\right) \\
&= \alpha\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}0\\-2\\4\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Can you find such $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: is the final answer  $\begin{bmatrix}
    3 \\
    -7 \\
    14 \\
  \end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 4):

We write the vector
$$x=\begin{bmatrix}
     -1 \\
   -4 \\
   3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
as a linear combination of the two vectors
$$u=\begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\
   -2 \\
   -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\quad;\quad v=\begin{bmatrix}
     -2 \\
   1 \\
   3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
so we look for $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$x=\alpha u+\beta v$$
hence we find using the components
$$-1=\alpha-2\beta\quad;\quad-4=-2\alpha+\beta$$
so we find $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=2$ and we verify that the third equality of components is valid with these values. Now the answer to the question is easy using the linearity of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-4\\\;\;3\end{pmatrix}=3\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1\\-2\\-1\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}-2\\\;\;1\\\;\;3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This hint comes "out of the blue":  they should find these constants themselves by solving a system of equations.

Comment: @StevenGubkin, apparently you're missing the word "hint" in the upper left corner...and if they "should" then one could say they "should" do the exercises by themselves. In my opinion, the point of this exercise is to understand and apply the linearity of the map, not to solve a rather boring and elementary linear system of equations.

Comment: I think this hint is overpowered.  Brian's hint below seems much more appropriate.

Comment: Hey, this guy does this and that guy does that. I know many times many answers are way better than mine, and I think many people can get useful hints and answers from here and there, @StevenGubkin In this case, for example, the other answer gives away all the meat in this exercise. Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: Didn't mean to offend.  I just saw this response posted after Brian's, and wished that other posters had waited to see if his hint was enough.  No hard feelings?

Comment: Brian and I posted almost at the same time as far as I recall, @StevenGubkin